# upgrading postgres version on Heroku, why upgrade the follower?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Heroku has [instructions on how to upgrade](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#database-bloat) postgres database version.

At a high level it's the following:

- provision a follower database (to follow primary db)
- put app into maintenance mode (so no new db transactions)
- upgrade follower
- promote follower to primary

**My question is - why is it recommended to upgrade the follower? Why not just upgrade the primary db? Then we wouldn't need to promote the follower either.**

I can see it's useful to have the follower as a backup incase the upgrade fails but I'm not clear on why we upgrade and promote the follower.